# Recursividad en SQL

Tags: sql, transact-sql

tengo el siguiente caso:
En el año 2017 un estudiante universitario curso y reprobó cálculo.
En el 2018 volvió a cursar la misma materia pero la aplazó, luego la volvió a matricular pero reprobó de Nuevo, en el 2019 volvió y matriculó y volvió y perdió.
En 2020 por fin la ganó

Año  #Matriculas

2017. ```
      "1"
      ```
2018. ```
      2
      ```
2019. ```
      1
      ```
2020. ```
      1
      ```

Cada año debo mostrar las veces que matriculó la materia adicionando los años anteriores así:

Año   #Matriculas

2017. 1
2018. 3 (1 del 2017 + 2 del 2018)
2019. 4 (1 del 2019 + 3 del 2018)
2020. 5 (4 del 2019 + 1 del 2020)

Creo que lo puedo lograr con recursividad, pero no he podido plantear la misma solo con T-SQL.

Me podrían ayudar o no se podria con recursividad o puedo resolverlo de otra manera?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Tengo una duda Off Topic: Cual es la diferencia entre **Reprobó, Aplazó y Perdió**?? Son sinónimos? No veo la utilidad puesto que con reprobó se entiende. O son diferentes formas de "no pasar" la susodicha materia o curso??

Comment: Yo aquí no veo código, y de lo que se trata en esta comunidad es de ayudar en errores de código que no consigas solucionar. Para que te hagan los deberes en su totalidad, prueba suerte en elRinconDelVago.

Comment: Ochoa, no son sinónimos, son conceptos diferentes, posibles resultados que puede tener 1 estudiante en un curso matriculado, el fin era obtener el número de veces que un estudiante matriculó ese curso ya logré realizarlo Muchas Gracias

Comment: Ferter3006 Vago el que entra aquí para criticar y no aportar igual muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas hacer es una suma acumulada, que se puede resolver sin recursividad. La forma más clásica y más compatible sería algo así:

```
SELECT  T1.Año,
        SUM(T2.#Matriculas) AS MatriculasAcumuladas
    FROM @TuTabla T1
    INNER JOIN @TuTabla T2
        ON T1.Año >= T2.Año
    GROUP BY T1.Año
    ORDER BY T1.Año
```

Un `join` de cada fila con la  misma tabla y las filas iguales y anteriores permiten hacer una agrupación y sumar de forma acumulada.

El SQL Server v2012 ya implementa funcionalidad de acumulación, por lo que podrías implementar algo así:

```
SELECT  Año,
        SUM(#Matriculas) OVER(ORDER BY Año ROWS 
                          BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                  ) AS MatriculasAcumuladas
    FROM @TuTabla
    ORDER BY Año
```

En este caso el `OVER` indica que la sumatoria la haga sobre la filas anteriores hasta la actual, Para más información consulta la documentación de la clausula [`OVER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Has algunas otras alternativas que podrías consultar en [How to get cumulative sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum)

Si quieres reproducir lo dicho, este es el código que hace reproducible mi respuesta:

```
declare @TuTabla TABLE (
    Año         INT,
    #Matriculas INT
)

INSERT INTO @TuTabla (Año, #Matriculas) VALUES (2017, 1), (2018, 2), (2019, 1), (2020, 1)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, entendí mal el ejercicio y planteé mal el mismo y la pregunta.

No era por año sino por periodo (en 1 año hay 4 periodos), por lo cual ya no era necesario acumular la suma sino solo un conteo:

Periodo 2017-1   Matricula = 1  --> (Reprobada)
Periodo 2017-2   Matricula = 2 (la actual y la del periodo anterior) --> Aplazada
Periodo 2017-3   Matricula = 3 (La actual, la aprobada y la aplazada) --> Aprobada:

Logré hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

[Número de Matricula] = ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER ( PARTITION BY Estudiante, Materia ORDER BY Año, Periodo  )

Answer (score 0):

Entendí mal el ejercicio y planteé mal el mismo y la pregunta.

No era por año sino por periodo (en 1 año hay 4 periodos), por lo cual ya no era necesario acumular la suma sino solo un conteo:

Periodo 2017-1   Matricula = 1  --> (Reprobada)
Periodo 2017-2   Matricula = 2 (la actual y la del periodo anterior) --> Aplazada
Periodo 2017-3   Matricula = 3 (La actual, la aprobada y la aplazada) --> Aprobada:

Logré hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

[Número de Matricula] = ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER ( PARTITION BY Estudiante, Materia ORDER BY Año, Periodo  )